# Do these random variables satisfy Lindeberg's condition?

Tags: random-variable, convergence, central-limit-theorem, indicator-function

I have the followig sequences:

1. $Pr(X_n=n)=Pr(X_n=-n)=0.5$
2. $Pr(X_n=2^{n/2})=Pr(X_n=-2^{n/2})=0.5$

I have to show whether they satisfy Lindeberg's condition or not, but this condition is a bit unclear for me.

$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{s_n^2} \sum^{n}_{k=1} \mathbb{E} [(X_k -\mu_k)^2 \cdot \mathbb{1}_{|X_k-\mu_k|>\epsilon s_n}]=0$

for all $\epsilon >0$.

The expected values of the r.v.-s  are $0$.

The variance in the first case: $n^2$, in the second case $2^n$.

In both cases the sums of the variances go to infinity. 
Isn't that enough for the condition to go to zero?

And I don't really understand that expression in the indicator function.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: This looks like routine bookwork. Is this for some class?

Comment: @Glen_b what routine bookwork for some may not be routine bookwork for someone else.

Comment: The point is that as the kind of question one might find in a textbook and could be set for a class, it would then count as a `self-study` question. See the [self-study tag wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Please add the tag and read the tag wiki info, modifying the question if needed.

Answer (score 6):

I will start with just some guidance, and perhaps return later to complete the answer.

Consider the first sequence of random variables, and note that $|X_n| = n$. In other words for given $n$, the absolute value of the random variable is a constant function (as is always the case for dichotomous random variables symmetric around zero).

Also, 
$$s^2_n = \sum_{i=1}^n\sigma^2_k = 1+2^2+3^2+...+n^2 =\frac {n(n+1)(2n+1)}6 = O(n^3)$$

Then the indicator function for some $k$ becomes

$$\mathbb{1}_{\left\{k>\epsilon \left(\frac {n(n+1)(2n+1)}6\right)^{1/2}\right\}}$$

Nothing random remains in here, so it can be taken out of the expected value, being a deterministic function.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: So, if n is very big even with a very small $\epsilon$ the right hand side will be bigger then k?

Comment: Give the left-hand side its best advantage: examine the leading indicator function (where $k=n$). If it weren't for the indicator functions, I guess you see that in this case the limit under examination would be equal to unity. So the issue is whether the existence of the indicator functions makes the numerator to have a fixed value, or to be bounded, or to be of lower order than the denominator

Comment: After a while we are summing zeros, right? So the whole expression will go to infinity.
But what about the 2.) case? 

$2^{k/2}>\epsilon (2^{n+1}-2)^{1/2}$

Comment: Square the expression

Comment: They have the same order. For The right hand side will be bigger for big epsilons, so again the condition doesn't hold, right?

Comment: Back to case 1). You wrote "the whole expression will go to infinity". What is the "whole" expression? Are you sure you have taken into account the $(1/s^2_n)$ term? And in any case, if the condition for the indicator function does not hold, the indicator becomes zero, which "weakens" the numerator, increasing the possibility that the whole expression will _go to zero_.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to write the "whole expression will go to zero" of course.